# pass sql file to nodejs for execution as whole

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am working on nodejs script that takes sql file containing large number of sql statements to be executed against mysql instance. Thus far, I've written two diff. nodejs functions that read-in sql statements one at a time from the specified sql file (storing each sql statement in nodejs object and iterating through to pass one statement at a time) and query those statements against the mysql instance. This methods works for simple sql queries, however, the queries I need to run are large and complex (and also written by multiple people, so the structure varies) so the one statement at a time approach fails when running these complex queries.

I've stumbled across execsql package for nodejs, which I believe takes an entire sql file as argument rather than querying one statement at a time (please correct me if I am wrong), but have been unable to get this package to work (https://www.npmjs.com/package/execsql).

```
var execsql = require('execsql'),
dbConfig = {
    host: 'cloud-address',
    user: 'db-user',
    port: 3306,
    password: 'user-pass'
},
sql = 'use test-db;',
sqlFile = __dirname + '/db.sql';
execsql.config(dbConfig)
.exec(sql)
.execFile(sqlFile, function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
}).end();

callback(err, results);
    ^ TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Any help is appreciated as to what nodejs packages should be achieved to do this (with the end goal of making it so that I can pass in a sql file that gets queried similar to if querying the file through a mysql-workbench shell).

Comment: Do you have a db.sql file in the directory with valid sql code in it? Sorry if that sounds obvious...

Comment: Hi Jacob. Yes, the file db.sql is in the right directory with valid sql code.

Comment: Hi ..how did you solve this I am getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
var execsql = require('execsql');
var callback = function(err,results){
  if (err){
    console.log("error is: ",err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("results is: ",results);
}
var dbConfig = {
    host: 'cloud-address',
    user: 'db-user',
    port: 3306,
    password: 'user-pass'
},
sql = 'use test-db;',
sqlFile = __dirname + '/db.sql';
execsql.config(dbConfig)
.exec(sql)
.execFile(sqlFile, function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
    callback(err, results);
}).end();
```

**callback(err, results); va dendro de la promesa, recuerda que node es asíncrono**

Comment: I tried using google translate and wasn't able to understand the full comment you made, can you please translate it in english if possible?

Comment: callback(err, results); Goes inside the promise, remember that node is asynchronous

Comment: function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
    callback(err, results);
}

Comment: oh okay, thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately I get the same error, even with callback(err, result) inside.

Comment: Ohh if I have noticed try doing the callback function

Comment: example function callback(err,results){}

Comment: **I'm going to modify the answer for you to try**

Comment: now I get an additional error along with the first one I listed in the original post: Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.

Comment: try in var sql ="SELECT NOW()";

Comment: This is another mistake you have